# Click the button to enable the input next to it in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

i found the tutorial like
[this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/jQuery/Form/Click_the_button_to_enable_the_input_next_to_it_in_jQuery.htm) but when I add the input, second input dont want to enable

here is code :

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function () {
$(this).next().removeAttr("disabled")
.focus()
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Enable</button>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="data" />
<input type=text disabled="disabled" value='data2'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to enable second input too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `.next()` target immediate next sibling. If you want to target both , then use `.nextAll()` along with disabled as attribute selector. also note that you can not focus both the elements together. for which you can use `.first()` to target first element in matched set along with `.focus()` to focus it :

```
$("button").click(function () {
 $(this).nextAll('[disabled]').removeAttr("disabled").first().focus()
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nvjnctzh/)**

Comment: because disabled is not the tag,input is.

Comment: @DickyMahardika: i am not getting you. can you elaborate.

Comment: what should I do to make it work. because I made it to edit data